# Is there a resource/site that I can use to practice harmonization?

Tags: harmony, self-learning

As above. With my theory exam in the distance, I want to brush up on harmonizing a given melody. Are there any sites/resources I could use to do this?

Comment: [Related](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/how-can-i-practice-harmony)

Answer (score 1):

there´s a software that can be useful:

http://harmonypractice.altervista.org/index.html

Hope this helps, good luck in your exams!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [free online class](https://class.coursera.org/classicalcomp-002) I am following on that very topic. I do not know if you have time to follow the entire class though.