# Im6 chord in a minor II-V-I

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions, harmony, jazz

In a minor II-V-I progression, we usually have a IIm7(b5) chord followed by a V7(b9,b13) chord, resolving into Im7. I always thought the diminished 5th in the II chord (also the minor 9th in the V7 chord, same note) was like a "hint" that a minor chord was coming, since it corresponds to the **minor 6th** of the I chord. That would be F in A minor/C major.

If you analyze the progression from a relative major standpoint:

```
VIIm7(b5) _ V7/VI(b9,b13) -> VIm7
```

In a major harmony, the VIm7 is related to the Aeolian mode and should have a minor 6th, right?

However, it came to my attention that some standards, like Autumn Leaves and Caravan (no II here, but a long time spent on V7b9), have this chord written and played as Im6 sometimes, with a **major 6th** instead. Is there a particular reason for this?

**Edit**: Is this a chord substitution? Some substitutions are based in harmonic concepts, like the tritone substitution. Does this major 6th thing have such an underlying concept?

Comment: Which chord is Im6 in Autumn Leaves? I've seen many different music sheets for the song, but never once seen a m6 chord  there; it isn't on the real book either. Ι've never seen any major 6th chord either there. But if you saw a I6, it is a common substitution for Imaj7

Comment: Em6 in G major versions, last chord of it's A section. Please note that it's Im6 in minor harmony (VIm6 in a major key like Autumn Leaves). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoxY_xPmJXg

Comment: So, your question is why is there a C in the E minor chord?

Comment: No, C is the minor 6th of E. I'm asking about the C#, which is the major 6th. Is my question unclear?

Comment: [A minor 6th chord is spelled 1 b3 5 6 which with a root of E is  E G B C#](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16932/why-does-a-cm13-chord-use-a-instead-of-ab). It's like any other substitution in Jazz it's function is _similar_, but the flavor is different.

Comment: Thank you for the link! However, I know how the chord is spelled. Most substitutions are based in harmonic concepts, like the tritone substitutions. Can you elaborate on this particular major 6th substitution? Does it have some kind of underlying concept? This is what I want to know.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a very relevant question.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic, you're right that books don't typically write in a `min6` chord. I think it was Miles Davis who popularized that sound--he actually [played the natural 6th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsp5OASh7bg#t=1m04s) in the melody over the minor i chord. This sound has become fairly common because many musicians use the intro from that same recording, which features a `G min 6` arpeggio in the bass and piano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that in minor the minor sixth of the key is part of the II chord, and it is a tension (b9) that is very often used on the V chord. However, it is *not* a valid tension on the I chord, because the minor sixth is an avoid note on that chord (basically because it is a half step above a basic chord tone, the 5). In [this blog post](http://www.mathiaslang.com/2014/11/avoid-notes.html) you can read more about avoid notes.

On the other hand, the major sixth is a valid tension on the I chord in minor. A minor 6 chord always contains the major sixth. It comes from the melodic minor scale. The I chord in minor comes in three basic flavors: Im6 (with a major 6th), Im7 (with a minor 7th), and Im maj7 (with a major 7th). The corresponding chord scales are melodic minor (for Im6 and Im maj7), and dorian (for Im7).

Comment: The linked blog post is an outstanding resource. It might be worth mentioning that a `I min6` chord doesn't *require* melodic minor. Dorian can also be used over a `I min6` chord.

Comment: @jdjazz: Thanks! ( I wrote that post :) And indeed, of course a minor 6th chord doesn't require anything, it's just that melodic minor is the most common and most natural choice, because it has no avoid notes when played over a m6 chord. Dorian contains all chord tones as well, but its 7th degree is an avoid note over that chord because it is a half step above the 6th. Melodic minor and dorian relate to a m6 chord a bit like Dorian and Aeolian to a m7 chord: both are possible but one is more natural because of the lack of an avoid note.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your overarching question is: **there's no requirement that the `ii` chord or the `V` chord share the same scale/chord tones as the `i` chord.** The `ii-V-i` progression will still sound good even whether or not a common scale is used across all three chords.

For example, it's not uncommon to play a Locrian ♯2 scale over the `ii` chord, an altered scale over the `V` chord, and then a melodic minor scale over the `i` chord. If you take a `ii-V-i` in `G min`, this would be *equivalent* to playing these chords and scales, respectively:

`|       Aø7       |       D7alt      |       Gmin      |       Gmin      |`

`| C melodic minor | E♭ melodic minor | G melodic minor | G melodic minor |`

There are plenty of notes that aren't shared across these three scales, but those scales nonetheless sound good over the ii-V-i.

That said, there might be reasons for choosing to play Aeolian vs. Dorian vs. melodic minor over the `i` chord. Matt L. mentions one possible reason for choosing dorian over Aeolian--because Dorian has fewer avoid tones. On the other hand, one might choose Aeolian for continuity with the `V alt` chord, as you suggest in your original post. Another factor one could consider when choosing a scale is the melody--if the melody uses a ♭6th over the `i min` chord, then maybe the solos should too. But there is no prescribed scale and the soloist often has freedom to choose which to use. So the Aeolian can be a great sound even despite its ♭6 avoid tone, but there's no rule that Aeolian is required over the `i min` chord to create continuity with the `iiø` or `V7alt` chords.

**A couple notes:**

A `i min6` chord is extremely common on Autumn Leaves, in large part thanks to Miles Davis, who in bar 7 plays the natural 6th in the melody instead of the root. ([This link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsp5OASh7bg#t=51s) starts after the intro, and the natural 6th is heard at 1:06.)

Playing `i min6` instead of `i min7` doesn't qualify as a substitution because we're playing the same chord, just with different alterations.