# The Truth About Cmb6

Tags: piano, chords

Cm6 contains an A Because the minor interval itself is derived from a major's. Cm: `C, Eb, G`. If Cm6 is built on its own minor scales `C, Eb, G, Ab`, then Cm7 will contain `C, Eb, G, A` instead of `C, Eb, G, Bb`. Because according to its minor scale , the 7th interval is already Bb. Cmb6 Contains `C, Eb, G, Ab`. Cb6 Contains `C, E, G, Ab`. The Ab is the b6.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Or was this supposed to be an answer to one of the other questions? Then something went wrong :)

Comment: OP seems to be answering https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/37957/why-does-a-minor-sixth-chord-contain-a-major-6th-interval, a question they have already tried to answer three times.

Comment: Alex - as has been asked before, we really need you to read our help pages to understand how Stack Exchange works. Currently you are posting inappropriately, which is why you are gaining downvotes and deletions.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is on the premise that the OP is asking how **Cm6** (and Cm7) are built.

A little knowledge is sometimes a dangerous thing! I think(?) here, you fell into the trap that the 6th note in C minor is Ab. Well, in some minor scales, the 6th degree *is* Ab - natural minor is one, **but** there's the melodic minor ascending which has Anat.

One thing is that Cm6 does not mean C with a minor 6 note - otherwise it would be C E G Ab - somewhat dissonant. Neither does it mean another dissonant C Eb G Ab. It is always C Eb G A, sounding a little better to boot.

True, the minor interval is derived from the major. (A minor interval is a semitone smaller than its major equivalent). **BUT** mainly as far as the *third* is concerned. Thus a major or minor key/scale/chord. Cm7 is in fact C Eb G Bb, not your C Eb G A, because A is the 6th note (of the melodic minor), thus producing Cm6.

After all this there's the rare-ish chord Cm maj7 - C Eb G B which again comes happily from the diatonics of C minor. No rules broken there either!

Cb6 exists, but not as you know it. It's more commonly called **B6**! spelled B D# F# G#...There is no use for a major (or minor) chord with a b6 note.

Comment: "There is no use for a major (or minor) chord with a b6 note." -- what about a b13? E.g. **C7b13**: C-E-G-Ab-Bb.

Comment: @DavidBowling - fair enough - except I meant a plain major or minor chord (triad). And the G and Ab together isn't going to sound too good...

Comment: Agreed, **C7b13** is a pretty _jangly_ chord, although sometimes that is the sound I am looking for.