# How can I construct the E7 only with theory?

Tags: theory, chords, notation, intervals

I have a hard time with the following description of what a E7 consists of: [image]

What does the *intervall* relate to here? I try to apply it to the *Notes* (Töne) above it (E B d gis b e`) but that can't fit.

E to B is not an 1 interval it is an interval of 7 (**E** F Fis G Gis A Ais *B*) and as I said I could not figure out where the 1 interval belongs to in the *Notes*. My teacher told me it is called E7 because it is a halfstep note lower to one of the root **E** notes (E or e`) so there needs to be a *Fis* (F#) somewhere in the notes description. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1-3-5-♭7 is a relative formula for building chords based on scale degrees of a major scale. 1 indicates the root of the chord so in this case E would map to 1.

From there, it's all directly mapped to the major scale. The 3rd scale degree of E major is G♯ (Gis), the 5th scale degree of E major is B, and the lowered 7th (♭7) is D.

If you were to try an build a dominant 7th on another root like C the same logic would follow. The 3rd scale degree of C major is E, the 5th scale degree of C major is G, and the lowered 7th (♭7) is B♭.

Comment: Ah now I got it! I just saw that it is not a triad because the "D" was added there which is the 10th interval (b septime or b7) since the real 7 is "D#" it needs to be lowered by one halfstep and there we have the D.
What I don't fully get is why it is called E7 and not Eb7 since it is not the 7th note of the major scale (which is D#) ?

Comment: For some reason the 7 seems to be borrowed from the minor scale -- if you want the major scale one you explicitly write Emaj7.

Comment: @xetra11 see https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/why-does-the-dominant-chord-contain-a-flattened-7th.

Comment: @LukeSawczak it's not derived from the minor scale, see the linked question above

Comment: @LukeSawczak I mean, technically you could argue that the D is borrowed from minor, but that would be pointless because the note D is also present in A major, so there's no point borrowing. (Note: it's A major, as E7 is diatonic to A major, which has the D).

Comment: No borrowing necessary. The chord E7 doesn't strictly belong to the key of E major. Yes, it gets used in key E a lot, but actually belongs to key A. It's the dominant chord of A. Key A uses D natural, and E7 is totally diatonic to key A.